# How to append text interactively as a list item to a list in the HTML document without storing the list item as a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is a question about how javascript compiles (I think) and how text gets appended to an HTML document.

I was following an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) because I wanted to append an element to a list in the document interactively.

My html file contains a list:

`<ul id="sList">
</ul>`

If I write javascript like this:

```
var textnode = document.createTextNode(s);
var node = document.createElement("li");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("sList").appendChild(node);
```

Each string (each held in the variable s) gets appended to a list in the document.

I naively thought I could write this in fewer lines.

```
var node = document.createElement("li");
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
document.getElementById("sList").appendChild(node);
```

works as intended, appending each s to a list as a list item, but each fails to appear as a list item properly if I try to reduce the code further by not storing the created "li" as a variable. For example, this script appends text between tags but not as list items:

```
var textnode = document.createTextNode(s)
var node = (document.createElement("li")).appendChild(textnode)
document.getElementById("sList").appendChild(node)
```

Similarly, my first attempt was this one-liner:

```
document.getElementById("sList").appendChild(document.createElement("li").appendChild(document.createTextNode(s)))
```

which also appends text within the `<ul>` tags but not as list items.

So I am just wondering how the compiler interprets an appendChild call of a text node to a document.createElement that hasn't been created yet, and whether it's possible to append items to a list without storing them as variables first. This question is out of curiosity, though I suppose it also would be nice to understand the DOM better and how do more with less javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I am just wondering how the compiler interprets an appendChild call of a text node to a document.createElement that hasn't been created yet...

It's not the compiler, it's the DOM. And the element **has** been created (you called `createElement`); what hasn't happened yet is that you haven't added it to the document, but that's fine, it's still an object, it can still have other objects attached to it.

> and whether it's possible to append items to a list without storing them as variables first.

Yes, by using the return value of `appendChild`, which [is the child element that was appended](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107):

```
list.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
```

So there we:

1. Create the `li` element
2. Append it to the list
3. Use the return value of appending it (the `li` element) to append the text node

> For example, this appends text between tags but not as list items:
>
> ```
> var textnode = document.createTextNode(s)
> var node = (document.createElement("li")).appendChild(textnode)
> document.getElementById("sList").appendChild(node)
> ```

That's because you're appending the return value of `appendChild` to the list. The return value of `appendChild` is the child that was appended, **not** the element it was appended to. So `node` refers to the text node. After appending that node to the `li`, you then *move* it to the `list` on the last line above.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this help! One question, what is your `list` variable above? Is it effectively `var list = document.getElementbyId("sList")`?

Comment: @jwco: Yeah, whatever reference you have to your list.